# Retrieve rows with highest salary per month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to do this but I don't know as. I have this table.

```
USER | SALARY  |   DATE
1234   1881,33     01/01/08
8762   2578        01/01/08
8726   2183,6475   01/01/08
2321   1745,8525   01/01/08
3123   1639,2      01/01/08
1934   2572        01/01/08
```

Is it possible to select from months of all years the person that has the bigger salary? In this case January 2008 was 8762.

Comment: Protip: [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: What is in your "salary" column? That doesn't look like monetary value...

Comment: @lad2025 I believe the comma is the decimal separator in this case, not used to indicate a list of values.

Comment: @aquinas they do in France :)

Comment: Yes,is monetary value

Comment: 1745,8525 huh. OK. I guess I'm not using to see 4 decimal places when dealing with money.

Answer (score 2):

I think yo can use a in clause for subselect with group by

```
select user from my_table 
where (salary, to_char(date,'mm-yyyy')) in 
   select(max(salary), to_char(date,'mm-yyyy') month_year 
        from my_table group by month_year);
```

Comment: Im little noob, what are you doing with 2011-01-17'?

Comment: This is a bit odd - you are finding all the users who had the highest monthly salary in at least one month, but you do not show who the winner was for each month. Perhaps this is what the OP wanted, but it seems strange. (Not sure what the OP wanted, his requirement may also be interpreted as find the user(s) who had the highest monthly salary ACROSS all months, not month by month.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using window function [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm).

It's used to enumerate rows in different groups ( in your case months - explanation below) ordered by salary in descending manner (in your case highest salary will be assigned a `rownum = 1` ):

```
SELECT 
 to_char(date_column, 'YYYY-MM'), 
 user
FROM (
 SELECT
 *,
 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY to_char(date_column, 'YYYY-MM') ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rownum
FROM yourtable
 ) foo
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY 1 -- not needed, looks nice in the results
```

Using [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function to get only the year and month part from your date and get the groups:

```
TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: SQL Developer says that there is a error here: extract(year_month from date_column) I think doesnt exist year_month

Comment: Do you say to do this?
`SELECT to_char(FECHA, 'YYYY-MM'), SSN FROM(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY to_char(FECHA, 'YYYY-MM') ORDER BY CUENTA DESC)
AS ROWNUM FROM
(SELECT A.SSN, (SUM(B.WAGE)- SUM(B.SALARY/(8*20))) CUENTA,trunc(REP_date,'mm') FECHA FROM REP_LINES A 
INNER JOIN COSTS B ON A.JOB=B.CAT_NUM and TO_CHAR(B.YEAR) = TO_CHAR(A.REP_DATE,'YYYY')
GROUP BY A.SSN,trunc(REP_date,'mm') ORDER BY FECHA)) FOO WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY 1;` The table 've changed to the query

Comment: SSN is user and FECHA is the date

Comment: @ConsiderMe - Yes, you linked the Oracle documentation... for MySQL, not for Oracle Database (the DBMS used by the OP). There is no extract (year_month) in Oracle Database.

Comment: @mathguy I stand corrected, that was my mistake. I've changed my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This query executed in mysql workbench..and worked as expected

```
select 
    DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`,'%Y-%m') AS date_field,
    max(salary) as salary
from
    employees
group by
    date_field;
```